# Untraceable datasheets of DC-DC buck converter (5 pin SOT23-5 IC) used in TP-LINK WiFi Router TL-WR720N V2

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, datasheet, wireless, router

I am trying to search the datasheets of DC-DC buck converters used in the TP-LINK WiFi Router TL-WR720N V2.

1. LD5AX and
2. TR5XF

A couple of years ago, an above mentioned router, belonging to one of my friends, went out of order due to plugging a 12 volts adaptor into it whereas it's rated input voltage was 5 volts. On inspecting its PCB, I found a 5 pin IC LD5AX blown on it.[image: LD5AX] It appeared a DC-DC buck converter because there was an inductor of unknown inductance in the circuit.
I tried to search the blown IC in the market but couldn't get one. Then I tried to search its datasheet on the internet, to decide any alternative for it, but remained unsuccessful. Therefore I fitted a buck converter based on LM2596 in the router and it started working.
Few days ago, somebody gave me the similar router which was operational but it had some configuration issues that I fixed after resetting it. Then I also looked at its PCB but found the 5 pin buck converter IC TR5XF, instead of LD5AX, for the same purpose. This time, I tried to search the datasheet of TR5XF on the internet but again remained unsuccessful to find the desired datasheet.
I shall be obliged if anybody can share with me the datasheets of above mentioned semiconductors.

Comment: LD5AX could be [this one](https://product.torexsemi.com/system/files/series/xc9236.pdf)

Comment: @Finbarr That would be a 3.5 V output voltage, which is a little unusual.... Not unbelievable though.